# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object for face recognition python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, mysql-connector-python

I want to do the face recognition for attendance program using python in which the program would detect a face, save the information of the user like ID and Name into people table in MySQL database, and then the program will recognize the face and insert the information of the saved user previously into another table, the attendance table. However, I have encountered an error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object" on the coding provided below:

```
            db = database.open()
            cursor_person = db.cursor()
            cursor_att = db.cursor()
            cursor_person.execute("SELECT pID, name_reg FROM people")
            for row in cursor_person.fetchone():
                pID, name_reg = row
                
                cursor_att.execute("UPDATE attendance(ppID, name_att) SET ('{}', '{}') WHERE" .format (pID, name_reg))
            db.commit()
```

The part where the error occurred is as shown below:

```
pID, name_reg = row <--- TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I hope the information that I have provided is helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think adding a `print` in the loop would help. That will show weather the problem is in the values or assigning them to `row`

Comment: What is the output of `row` value? The `row` variable is not returning two values.

Comment: @Ahx I want to insert the pID and name_reg from table 'people' into 'attendance' table with the same value, ID and Name. or did the query that I use is wrong?

Comment: @AbrarAhmed I have tried it but I'm not really sure where is the problem because I get the same error once again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to use [fetchall](https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/#:%7E:text=fetchall()%20fetches%20all%20the,cursor.)
Note that your update sql phrase is broken.

```
 for row in cursor_person.fetchall():
     cursor_att.execute("UPDATE attendance SET ('{}', '{}') WHERE" .format (row[0], row[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to debug this is to `print(row)` and see what it is.

But I'm guessing your real problem is that those two cursors aren't isolated since they share the same session. The `cursor_att.execute()` line is probably causing `cursor_person.fetchone()` to return the number of updated rows, an int `1`.

Lastly, you shouldn't use `.format` to set the UPDATE clause values. Otherwise you're at risk of SQL injection attacks, or just accidental bugs on your own part when values contain characters like `'`. There's an [example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) on how to properly pass in parameters like so:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE attendance SET (%s, %s)", (pID, name_reg))
```

And the mysql-connector library will automatically escape the strings for you.